# Open Excel file using a variable that references the file

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

In Excel VBA I write: 
Set mWB = Application.Workbooks("File.xlsx")

Then: mWB.Close() I noticed is a possibility, but in the autocomplete list I only see close, not open.

How can I open an excel file in VBA using a variable of type Excel (Dim mWB As Workbook) that holds a reference to the file?

I don't want to use:  Application.Workbooks.Open ("File.xlsx"), which I know is possible!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that isn't how that class works. If you wanted to though, you could create a class to do that?

Comment: Workbook objects store references to workbooks that are in memory. If the workbook is closed, it cannot be referenced as a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set mwb = Application.Workbooks.Open ("File.xlsx")
```